# Login and access pages of a website using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, authentication, session-cookies

So I'm trying to write some code that goes to a website (an internal confluence wiki) and retrieves specific html pages.  I have the part of the code that decodes the html with BeautifulSoup working, however I've hit a road block because it requires a log in before I can access the pages.  I've tried using requests and urllib with no success.  Also I'm using Python 3.4.

```
def log():
    URL = 'confluence page here'
    EMAIL = '****'
    PASSWORD = '****'

    # Start a session so we can have persistant cookies
    session = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr})

    # This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
    login_data = {
        'loginemail': EMAIL,
        'loginpswd': PASSWORD,
        'submit': 'login',
    }

    # Authenticate
    r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)

    # Try accessing a page that requires you to be logged in
    r = session.get(page i want to access)
    return r
```

However I get an error `TypeError: session() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'`.  Does anyone know a way to login to confluence wiki then grab the html source of an arbitrary number of pages?  I would prefer to avoid using any unsupported packages.

Comment: There have been API changes in recent versions of `request`, see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#api-changes , which may be what's biting you.  In particular, and I quote, "The config parameter to the requests method has been removed. [snip] The verbosity option should be handled by configuring logging."

Answer (score 2):

Alright I managed to figure it out and here is how I did it.

```
email = input('username: ')
password = getpass.getpass(prompt = 'password: ',stream =None)
url = '##login page'

login_data = {
    'os_username': email,
    'os_password': password,
    'login': 'Log In',
}
s = requests.session()
s.post(url, login_data)
```

so its important to understand how the html works which I didnt at the time of asking, but you need to inspect the html and look for what the login calls the variable in my case it was os_username.  then you can construct a dictionary like I did in login_data.  Then using requests which I imported above the shown code you post the data and create a session which will keep you logged in so long as you are inside the method.  Hopefully this will get me some sweet sweet brownie points on here. :)